# How do SPAs handle Not Modified 304 response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, http, single-page-application

Let’s say a Single Page Application (SPA) written in angular or vuejs for example loads 3 components on a page and each component calls a different backend api.

Then, a user refreshes the page. The same 3 calls are made but this time, the backend returns 304 for each of them.

The SPA components are just js code. So with each call to the backend they expect data returned. When a 304 is returned. There’s no data. However things function fine...

There’s some magic I don’t understand. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: You might want to ask about a particular front-end framework and how to best handle it in that environment as each has its own patterns to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The server will only return a 304 response with no content if the client includes an `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` request header. Without those headers the server will always respond with the full content. There's now two possibilities:

- The Javascript code itself adds those headers because it still has the data somewhere, to explicitly allow empty responses. The Javascript code may have stored the data in local storage.
- The browser includes those headers because it still has an implicit cache of the data, and if the server returns 304, it transparently returns the cached data to the Javascript request. I'm not sure whether browsers actually do this; I believe not, but it's a possibility.

It's more likely the Javascript is managing a local cache, perhaps with a web worker.

Comment: It's worth noting that this shouldn't happen with an API, only static assets.

Comment: Yes, I think XHR requests are exempt from implicit caching.